# ubuntu 16.04 PXE installation

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, kernel, pxe

Can I install Ubuntu OS 16.04 using PXEboot without upgrading the packages and kernel?

When I am installing new OS the kernel is getting upgraded to latest version. I need to install the server with old kernel version.

Thanks

Comment: Do you control the pxeboot server? I'm pretty sure you can turn off automatic updates.

Comment: Yes. I do control the PXE server. But during installation it is downloading and upgrading all the packages and kernel to latest version. I do not have a local repo and all the latest packages are pulled from global repo.

Comment: How do I turn off the automatic updates? I did remove the preseed folder from the boot but still the packages are getting updated.

Comment: In the preseed file uncomment the line "d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none"

Comment: BTW, why do you need to use an old kernel?

Comment: I have a tool that does not work beyond 16.04.1. So this is the main reason why I want to hold on to upgrading kernel during installation.

Comment: Okay, well, I'm sorry I'm not too helpful, I don't have a useful ubuntu machine at the moment. I was hoping the debian installer thing was a good clue. You could try searching the installer kickstart directory like this: "grep -r pkgsel/upgrade *"

Comment: Sure. No problem. Thanks! I did find pkgsel/upgrade and set the value to none but the kernel is still upgrading. Below are the changes I have made inorder to restrict kernel upgrade:preseed pkgsel/upgrade select none
preseed base-installer/kernel/image string linux-generic_4.4.0.116.122_amd64.deb
preseed base-installer/install-recommends boolean false
preseed live-installer/net-image string /install/filesystem.squashfs

Comment: So you figured it out? Great! Please make it into an official answer so people can read it more easily.

Comment: Its not working. when I giving kernel as none it is not downloading any kernel. At boot it is sending me to grub prompt.

Answer (score 0):

In the preseed file uncomment the line

```
d-i pkgsel/upgrade select none
```

Comment: I am using ks file generated from kickstart tool in ubuntu. Is there a way I can configure preseed file?